# Find dropdown menu configurations with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am wondering if there is a way to find out whether a dropdown menu is shown on click or on hover event, using jquery.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add Event Listeners for click, keyup, keypress, change and blur. Use setting a class or whatever you want to save the state, on blur always remove the open state.

```
<select>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option>
</select>


$("select").on('click keyup keypress change blur', function(event){
    $(this).toggleClass('isOpen');
    if (event.type == 'blur') {
      $(this).removeClass('isOpen'); 
    };
});
```

Comment: There is an existing drop down menu which is show when one event happens. I don't want to open the menu when an event happens. I just want to find out which event triggers the menu to be shown, without pressing any key or clicking.